# One-way function with combination sets as output / image

Tags: one-way-function

One-way functions generally operate on bit strings, for the input and the output.

Are there any examples of one-way functions that produce a combination set in output? Let's call this function $f$. The function would take one bit string in input, of size $p$, and would produce a combination ($k$ elements among $n$). $n$ is a power of $2$.

Concrete example of combinations set: 64 elements among 256. The size of this set is 1.9E+61 (204 bits)

I have an algorithm to generate a combination through a hash function: the hash function is used to generate a pseudo random bit string, then the bit string is split into sub-strings of size $\log_2(n)$ whose value represents the position of the element in the set of size $n$. If the value was already selected, to check the next value. If the hash function has good properties the loop will stop after some iterations.

I would like to know whether there are constructions considered as primitives for this problem.

Comment: A bitstring can encode any object, so just take any OWF and parse its output as whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, there's a prior art here.

The random oracle / hash function used in [BLISS signature scheme](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/383) hashes a certain bit string into a sparse vector (see section 4.4). And the way they do it, is similar to what you just described.

I've got an old code sample [lying around](https://sf.net/p/mysuitea) you can reference, I've incorporated a few later improvements.